# Number lines and hide the empty ones

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to number the lines of a txt file and hide the empty ones . I use this code :

```
cat -n file.txt | grep . file.txt
```

But it doesnt work . It ignores the cat command . I want to display all the non-empty lines and number them ( the txt file is not a static one , like a list that a user can type in ).

edit : Given the great solutions below , i would also add that `grep . file.txt | cat -n` also worked .

Comment: please update the question with a) some sample data from `file.txt` and b) the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to number the lines that remain after the empty lines are removed.

### Solution #1

Use `sed '/^$/d'` to delete the empty lines then pipe its output to `cat -n` to number them:

```
sed '/^$/d' file.txt | cat -n
```

The `sed` program contains only one command: `d` (delete the line). The `sed` commands can be prefixed by zero, one or two addresses that tell what lines the command applies to.

In this case there is only one address `/^$/`. It is a `regex` (enclosed in `/`) that selects the empty lines; the lines where start of the line (`^`) is followed by the end of the line (`$`).

### Solution #2

You can also use `grep -v '^$'` to filter out the empty lines:

```
grep -v '^$' file.txt | cat -n
```

Again, `^$` is a regular expression that matches the empty lines. `-v` reverses the condition and tells `grep` to display the lines that do not match the `regex`.

---

The commands above do not modify the file. They read the content of `file.txt`, process it and display the result on screen.

#### Update

As @robc suggests in a comment, [`nl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nl.1.html) is even better than `cat -n` to number the lines. Thank you @robc, I didn't know about `nl` until now (I didn't know about `cat -n` either). It is never too late to learn new things.

Comment: Pipe to [`nl`](https://ss64.com/bash/nl.html) instead of `cat -n` if you want greater control of formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily done with `awk`. This will print line with line numbers and ignore empty lines.

```
awk 'NF{print FNR,$0}' file.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '             ##Starting awk program from here.
NF{               ##Checking condition if NF(number of fields) is NOT NULL in current line then do following.
 print FNR,$0     ##Printing current line number by mentioning FNR and then current line value.
}
' file.txt        ##Mentioning Input_file name which we are passing to awk program here.
```

Comment: @GeorgeIliopoulos: Slightly more detailed version: `awk '{ if(NF!=0) {print NR,$0} }' file.txt` See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)